# Search and replace contents of text file based on mappings in CSV file in C#

Tags: c#, csv, replace

I am new to programming and am working on a C# project that will search and replace certain words in a text file with new values.  I have some code that works, but the OLD and NEW values are hardcoded right now.  I would like to use an external CSV file as a configuration file so the user can add or update the OLD to NEW mappings at a later time.  This is my current code with the OLD and NEW values hardcoded:

```
try
{
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(inputfullfilepath);
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputfile);

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        line = line.Replace("OLD1", "NEW1");
        line = line.Replace("OLD2", "NEW2");
        // etc....

        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
    file.Close();
    File.Move(inputfullfilepath, inputfullfilepath + ".old");
    writer.Close();
    File.Move(outputfile, outputfilepath + @"\" + inputfilename);
    MessageBox.Show("File Scrub Complete", "Success");
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error:  Be sure data paths are valid.", "Error", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
```

The code takes each line of the text file, tries to do a search/replace for all OLD to NEW mappings, then goes to the next line in the text file.  The problem I am trying to wrap my head around is being able to make this list of OLD to NEW mappings dynamic based on a CSV (or XML if that would be easier?) configuration file so the user can add new search/replace keywords.

I tried to use the C# Application Settings in Visual Studio (which creates an XML configuration file) but I had a really hard time understanding how to make that work.  What's the best way to do this so the values don't have to be hardcoded?

Answer (score 0):

A csv file will work just fine.

I'll create a new Object which i'll call ReplaceObject

```
public ReplaceObject()
{
public string original;
public string updated;

//ideally you'd use getters and setters, but I'll keep it simple
}
```

Now we read from the csv

```
List<ReplaceObject> replaceList = new List<ReplaceObject>

while (reader.peek != -1)
{
string line = reader.readln();

var splitLine = line.split(',');

ReplaceObject rObject = new ReplaceObject();

rObject.original = splitLine[0];
rObject.updated = splitLine[1];

replaceList.add(rObject);

}
```

Now we go through the list.. and replace

```
string entireFile = //read all of it

foreach (ReplaceObject o in replaceList)
{
entireFile.Replace(o.original,o.updated);
}

//write it at the end
```

(Note that my code is missing some checks, but you should get the idea.  Also you might want to use a StringBuilder)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be that you use the `Settings.cs` instead of CSV

It is very easy to use them and involves very less code

```
e.g. Properties.Settings.Default.Old1;
```

Here is a walkthrough http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

See this example showing how you can use it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17659/How-To-Use-the-Settings-Class-in-C